# Is it possible to create a custom package in buildroot that use a private GitHub repository?

Tags: github, buildroot

I want to create a custom package for buildroot that uses a private GitHub repository as source code. I have configured the repo for use ssh credencial.

I'm wondering how to write the package to git clone with ssh permision, since GitHub do not permit https access (only ssh).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested, but I believe you can set

```
FOO_SITE = git@github.com:mygroup/foo
FOO_SITE_METHOD = git
```

This will use your ssh public key to log in with github.